# Disable Right click on windows ce

Tags: c#, windows-ce, right-click

We have an application that runs on fullscreen but if I keep my fingers pressed on the borders of the application (corners), I get the right click menu (copy paste etc). I need to programmatically disable right click so that that window wouldn't open.

Edit: I want to disable right click on device level, **NOT application level.**

Is there any way of doing it? If so how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are the OEM of your target device, you can disable aygshell API (SYSGEN_AYGSHELL= 0), but you may lose other features also.